# Download custom tiles from OSM with specified zoom levels?

Tags: openstreetmap

I would like to download openstreetmap tiles which would be used in leaflet.js to implement in a hobby application.
I have been looking for the internet for 2 hours, but cant seem to find a solution for my usecase.

- The main thing i would need is to select the areas that i wish to download (a route from A to B and about 20 kms from the route). I does not need to be perfectly 20 kms but i would like to minimise the needed data.
- I do not need all the zoom levels like from 0-16. I would only need 3-4 so it also helps to minimise the data. And these zoom levels are not necessarily following each other, so not 1-2-3-4 but something like 1-2-4-8.

What service or an app can do these?

Comment: Have a look at SAS.Planet https://sasplanet.software.informer.com/11.0/, here is the latest version download: https://bitbucket.org/sas_team/sas.planet.bin/downloads/